# How can I automatically download pages I've surfed so I can view them while offline?

Tags: internet, firefox-extensions, browser-cache

I would like it if every single page that I ever view (not based on query string, only URL) would automatically be cached so that I could view them again if I am offline.

For example I have saved a lot of bookmarks for managing ESXi, however if I follow the bookmarks it reloads the page as expected.

How can I permanently and automatically save the resource so that if the original location removes the content I will still have the information on my system?

I do not want this to be cleared however if I delete all browser data.

Maybe there is a firefox plugin for this?

Comment: "Can you run off a few copies of the internet for me?"

Comment: Sure but I think there's a new version already :(

Comment: Small correction: The query string *is* part of the URL; and there are many websites (for example, Drupal-based, or many news sites) that only have one index.html and use the query string for *everything*.

Comment: @mmyers: there is a joke: man finds advertisement in newspaper saying "selling internet on DVDs". He asks the man, how many dvds and he says something like "999 999 999 DVDs". "Too much." "Okay, if you want, I can burn it on only 10 DVDs, but without porn." :-D

Comment: @grawity this I know, however that does not change my desired functionality of the automatic saving, however for now I only found a manual solution which eliminates the need for that detail

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, looks like I may have already found what could work for this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

It may not be automatic, but I have already set it up so I can instantly save page copies to Dropbox by pressing the shortcut key. Sweet!